# How to correctly use this.added

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I'm trying to publish a collection and I would like to add in a field that doesn't exist in the collection. I might be way off track here but I thought I could use `this.added()` to add fields to the published collection. Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong

```js
Meteor.publish('job.view-open-to-candidate', function(jobCollectionId) {
  const job = Jobs.find({ _id: jobCollectionId }, {
    fields: {
      candidateApplication: 0
    }
  });

  this.added('job', jobCollectionId, {testNewField: 'test'})

  return job;
});
```

Comment: Is this on the right track https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175965/using-this-added-in-meteor

Comment: Yeh, I tried to implement that earlier with no luck. I'm not sure why though? @Mikkel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify documents in publication you should use [`Cursor.observe()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe) or [`Cursor.observeChanges()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges).

The most common pattern for that is (with modification you need):

```js
Meteor.publish('job.view-open-to-candidate', function(jobCollectionId) {
  const publication = this;

  const handle = Jobs.find({ _id: jobCollectionId }, {
    fields: {
      candidateApplication: 0
    }
  }).observeChanges({
    added(_id, fields) {
      const newFields = fields;
      newFields.testNewField = 'test';
      publication.added('jobs', _id, newFields);
    },

    changed(_id, fields) {
      const newFields = fields;
      newFields.testNewField = 'test';
      publication.changed('jobs', _id, newFields);
    },

    removed(_id) {
      publication.removed('jobs', _id);
    },
  });

  this.ready();

  this.onStop(() => {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

Comment: I need to go through this step by step to understand how it works but it does. Thank you for posting!

Comment: One question. This works, however, within the code you don't return anything. Can you shed some light on how this works?